# Local Day from posixct

Tags: r, datetime, timezone, posixct

I've been working with some data recorded in a workplace in Hawaii, using UTC time instead of local time. Because Hawaii has a large UTC offset (UTC-10:00), this means that UTC midnight will happen in the middle of the office day, making it important to localize my dates.

Unfortunately, `as.Date()` uses UTC dates and not Hawaiian dates, like so:

```
example_time <- as.POSIXct("8/1/14 0:05", tz = "UTC", format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M")
example_time
# [1] "2014-08-01 00:05:00 UTC"
attributes(example_time)$tzone <- "Pacific/Honolulu"
example_time
# [1] "2014-07-31 14:05:00 HST"
as.Date(example_time)
# [1] "2014-08-01"
weekdays(example_time)
# [1] "Thursday"
weekdays(as.Date("2014-08-01"))
# [1] "Friday"
```

What should I use instead of these date objects if I am using `dplyr` to summarize some observations taken at different times of each day, and then plotting this summary on a graph? The best solution would be one that works well if I can `dplyr::group_by()` it, especially since Dates also look good plotted on a `ggplot` graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`as.Date` has a `tz` option, did you try that?

```
as.Date(example_time)
## [1] "2014-08-01"
as.Date(example_time, tz='Pacific/Honolulu')
## [1] "2014-07-31"
```

Comment: I didn't think to check that dates could have time zones. Is there an easy way to do this without manually specifying the time zone, or is there nothing easier than `as.Date(example_time, tz=attributes(example_time)$tzone)`

Comment: Have you tried writing a helper function to do just that?

Comment: Ya know, that might be the best way to do this. I'm curious, is the non-portability of time zones between `POSIXct` and `Date` expected behavior? Seems quirky to me.

Comment: It makes sense for date boundaries to default to GMT. That way, regardless of your timezone, there is no unclarity about what date it is.